# Disable the public key check for rpm installation

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm, public-key

I want to make a DVD with some useful packages (for example php-common). The only problem is that if I try to install on a computer that's not connected to internet, I can't validate the public key.

The scenario is like this:

1. I download the RPMs, I copy them to DVD.
2. I install CentOS 5.5 on my laptop (it has no internet connection).
3. I try install one using yum (or `rpm -i`, or whatever).

I get the following error: public key for "package" is not installed.

How can I bypass that?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

From `yum -h`:

> ```
> --nogpgcheck          disable gpg signature checking
> ```

Comment: What if the network-less system is older (i.e. CentOS 5) and its yum does *not* have a nogpgcheck option?

Comment: change yum.conf to switch gpgcheck to 0

Answer (score 15):

For legacy RPM Linux without `yum` use:

`rpm -i --nosignature`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to disable the GPG validation for the whole Repo, add the following line to the Repo definition in /etc/yum.conf:

gpgcheck=0

If you are installing local RPMs using yum, do as Ignacio says.